# EF6 Code First Migration with single database multiple context

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I'm building an Asp.net MVC5 + EF6 solution with 3 projects.
I have enabled automatic migration in my project.
The below diagram shows my project structure.

[image]

1. I have a main project and two sub projects.
2. I have a `BaseContext` in a main project.
3. Sub project has their own `context` classes which derives from
   `BaseContext`.
4. All above contexts are connecting to one database.

**Models:**

A Model in Project2

```
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public int ProductId {get;set;}
    ...
}
```

A Model in Project3

```
public class Order
{
    [Key]
    public int OrderId {get;set;}

    [ForeignKey("Product")]
    public int ProductId {get;set}

    public virtual Product Product;

    ...
}
```

An property from *Project3* entity (`Order.ProductId`) references a property from *Project2* entity  `(Product.ProductId)` as a foreign key reference.

When I run `update-database`command in  project 1 & 2 everything is going well.
But when run `update-database` command in project 3 It gives an error:

> There is already an object named 'Product' in the database.

Right now I'm using `update-database -script` command to generate script and manually altering the script. But when project grows, it becomes a difficult task to alter sql scripts each and every time.

I ignored the `Product` entity by adding `modelBuilder.Ignore<Product>()` inorder to skip table creation for `Product`entity, in *Project3*, but it's ignores the entire relationship.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: I have a similar problem where it is the same database, but added a new DB Context that includes new tables and some that are shared with the other DB Context. The 2 contexts are for different business problems. When I add a migration, EF 6 wants to create all the new tables, but also wants to create existing tables that reside in the older DB Context. I guess I may have to just edit the migration that EF is creating before doing the update-database. Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this. One context == one database. When you run a migration against a database for a particular context, it will be based on that context, and will remove any non-applicable tables or try to drop and recreate the database.

You should move all your entities into a class library, along with a single instance of a context that includes them all. Then, you can migrate against the class library and simply reference in your other projects.

Alternatively, you can sort of do what you want by going with an existing database approach. Essentially, you turn off migrations entirely on your base context, and then each sub context can then only include the entities that belong to it. However, you're going to be completely responsible for managing the database, yourself, at that point.

```
public class BaseContext : DbContext
{
    public BaseContext()
        : base("ConnectionString")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<BaseContext>(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't like to move all the entities to a class library. In my project's sub projects are class libraries.  My main objective to separate them into multiple projects is to minimize the complexity when project grows larger.  If  One context == one database then what is the best practice to share the single context with multiple projects? How to make migration job easy in such situation?

Comment: You can separate out the entities into multiple class libraries if you want, but they still have to basically come together into one main class library that would include your context and simply reference all those other libraries. However, you'd still have an inherent dependency on each library in any app that needs the context, since the context library would have to reference all the others. In other words, this would only be for your own solution organization purposes. You couldn't simply pick or choose which entity projects are reference by which apps.

Comment: Again, that's the nature of code first with migrations. A single context must house every entity that belongs to the database it represents. Like I said early, you can sidestep this by simply not allowing EF to manage your database, and instead take that on yourself. Then, you can have as many contexts as you like, referencing whatever you like.